# Auto Fill macro captures extra data

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="0"
    ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & Rows.count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[ccc]Cos'!R2C3:R400000C4,2,False)"
     
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I try to use this to code to autofill all visible cells in column E. The reason it has to be visible rows is that it runs a filter before the code. However, the code above seem to be wrong can someone help me fix the above code in a similar format if possible

Comment: Pretty sure you can't fill a discontinuous range like that.

Comment: Could you share what exactly is selected and its contents (the formula)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 i have added the whole code in a edit

Answer (score 0):

### Write Formula to Discontinuous Range

- You cannot use `AutoFill` on a discontinuous range but you can write the formula to all cells in one go.
- If you use variables, everything becomes clearer. Of course, it'll take some time to get used to them.
- The leading `d` stands for *Destination*. The *Source* workbook (`ccc`) and worksheet (`Cos`) are only referred to in the formula.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteFormulas()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData ' clear any filter
    
    ' Set the Table range (has headers) e.g. 'A1:J10'.
    Dim dTrg As Range: Set dTrg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Set the (Table) Data range (no headers) e.g. 'A2:J10'.
    Dim dDrg As Range: Set dDrg = dTrg.Resize(dTrg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    dTrg.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="0"
    
    ' Set the Visible Data range (no headers) e.g. 'D2:D3,D5,D7,D9:D10'.
    Dim dVDrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no filtered rows (cells)
        Set dVDrg = dDrg.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    dws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off filter
    
    ' Write formula.
    If Not dVDrg Is Nothing Then
        dVDrg.FormulaR1C1 _
            = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[ccc]Cos'!R2C3:R400000C4,2,False),"""")"
    End If
    
End Sub
```